# Stuck in a restart loop after fresh Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS installation

Tags: boot, 20.04, system-installation, lenovo

I'm stuck in a restart loop after installing Ubuntu. I tried everything I could but it didn't help. I also tried reinstalling.

After restarting the screen flickers once displaying:

```
[136.270728] sd-umoun[5824]: Failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy
[136.271541] sd-umoun[5825]: Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev/pts: Device or resource busy
[136.272356] sd-umoun[5826]: Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev: Device or resource busy
[136.274237] shutdown[1]: Could not detach loopback /dev/loop0: Device or resource busy
[136.275094] shutdown[1]: Failed to finalize file systems, loop devices, ignoring
```

[image: Failed to unmount]

Then it displays `Reset System` in the corner and starts to loop.

[image]

Device:

- Lenovo ideapad slim 1
- RAM 4gb
- 250 gb ssd
- intel N4020 1.1GHz
- Windows 10 Home preinstalled

Comment: I'm a newbie and i followed the exact steps for installation from ubuntu official website.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1278795/1222991) regarding a similar problem? 

Comment: i've same laptop with celeron. did you try to change to UEFI boot?

Comment: This may not help, but when I personally installed Ubuntu, I enabled UEFI, and chose the UEFI option on the boot menu.

Comment: yeah i did. I also tried legacy support.

Comment: i have seen these warnings during installation [https://askubuntu.com/questions/832524/possible-missing-frmware-lib-firmware-i915] will this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue, changed boot mode from "UEFI Hybrid" mode in the BIOS to the "UEFI Native" mode. The restarts stopped happening and the system booted normally.

This was on a HP Elitebook 820 G1.