# Ubuntu Could Not Detach Loopback

Tags: system-installation, 22.04

I wanted to switch to Ubuntu so I flashed a USB drive and installed Ubuntu. After installing, the computer asked me to restart, and after restarting I got this error message which I don't really know how to handle. If someone has encountered this before, help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
sd-unmoun[123456]: Failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy
sd-unmoun[123457]: Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev: Device or resource busy
shutdown[1]: Could not detach loopback /dev/loop0: Device or resource busy
shutdown[1]: Failed to finalize file systems: loop devices, ignoring.
```

Comment: I made a typo. I meant USB drive, although I don't think that will help.

Comment: If it is done installing, remove the USB drive and just reboot the system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stuck in a restart loop after fresh Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377658/stuck-in-a-restart-loop-after-fresh-ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-installation)