# I cannot shutdown Ubuntu 22.04. Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, mount, shutdown, recovery-mode

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows on an HP Victus with an Nvidia 3050 ti mobile and I cannot shut down Ubuntu properly. During the shutdown I get the following error messages:

```
Failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy
Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev/pts: Device or resource busy
Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev: Device or resource busy
Failed to finalize file systems, ignoring
```

Some forums said that maybe there's an error with the Nvidia drivers. I tried to uninstall them but it didn't help. In Recovery mode Ubuntu shuts down properly.

These are the photos of my BIOS settings. I cannot find where I can change the UEFI mode to Legacy/Native

BIOS settings:

[image: BIOS Settings Image 1]

[image: BIOS Settings Image 2]

[image: BIOS Settings Image 2]

Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: If dualboot with windows please check https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230403/failed-to-unmount-oldroot-dev-warning-during-the-shutdown-or-restart

Comment: I have the same problem and I have fixed it by referencing [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426205/ubuntu-22-04-stuck-at-shutdown)